# HDFS Namenode HA: Why use NFS rather than simply replicate between the two?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability

Looking at the AvatarNode solution used by Facebook to provide HA for the HDFS Namenode, I don't understand the reason why NFS is used.  What's confusing to me is that NFS has to replicate anyway in order to achieve HA.  The primary has to write to NFS and flush in order to have HA.  Why not simply open up a socket channel between the primary and the secondary and perform the same writes to the secondary Namenode.  It would be (approximately) the same amount of network traffic and would seem to have the same replication semantics.

So the question is, why isn't this done?

I suppose that one reason could be that NFS exists and so the problem may be perhaps simpler to implement.  But given the (apparent) simplicity of using raw socket channels between the primary and secondary writing the same information that's written to the stream interface (i.e. a file) to NFS, I'm left scratching my head as to why this hasn't been done yet.

Surely there must be some good reason for opting to use NFS that I'm missing in my armchair analysis.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, but I agree in that this seems like a very odd choice, and I really can not think of any other reason but that the team tasked with fixing something had a functioning NFS setup that had worked for some other use. But based on my experiences I consider NFS yet another single-point to fail and would not choose it for cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I found this post on AvatarNodes: http://hadoopblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hadoop-namenode-high-availability.html

It seems to me that the AvatarNode allows you to minimize downtime when the name node goes down and be back up with a new name node in less than a minute.

From the hadoop [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#What_is_the_purpose_of_the_secondary_name-node.3F):

```
The term "secondary name-node" is somewhat misleading. It is not a name-node in the   
sense that data-nodes cannot connect to the secondary name-node, and in no event it can 
replace the primary name-node in case of its failure.
```

Since the secondary name node cannot act as a name node, it brings up the possibility of a lengthy downtime in recovering or starting up a new name node.

The AvatarNode can act as both a secondary and primary and allows rapid failover, just by switching a VIP.

In regards to why use NFS and not sockets, the post says

```
It is guaranteed that the Standby AvatarNode ingests all committed transactions because    
it reopens the edits log and consumes all transactions till the end of the file; this 
guarantee depends on the fact that NFS-v3 supports close-to-open cache coherency 
semantics.
```

I think this is a matter of minimizing data loss when the name node goes down and maintaining consistency with the HDFS edits data. More about the close-to-open consistency guarantee here: http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_a8

Comment: Thanks.  I did understand what the Avatarnode design is doing and the problem it's trying to solve.  What I'm questioning is the implementation using NFS.  It seems like it should be fairly trivial to replicate the information between the primary and the secondary directly, rather than adding another system of failure into the mix.

Comment: thanks for the addition.  However, it seems like the close-to-open semantics seem trivial to maintain between the primary and the secondary using simple sockets to replicate the state between them.

Answer (score 0):

Hal, [this](https://twitter.com/tlipcon/status/213013135798435840) might answer your question (esp. the "kicking the can down the road" bit)..